# Typescript super() vs new ()

Tags: typescript

Given two classes, `ClassA`and `ClassB

```
ClassA{
    public foo;
    constructor(){
        this.foo = 'hey!';
    }
}
```

What is the difference between :

```
ClassB extends ClassA{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

and

```
ClassB{
    private a;
    constructor(){
        this.a = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

The reason I'm asking this is because I've implemented the first scenario, but whenever I call `super.foo` I get `undefined` but if I call `this.a.foo` from the second scenario, I get the value.

What is the difference between calling `super()` and instantiating a new instance of the parent class?
I am using TypeScript 2.1.5

Answer (score 1):

if I try

```
class A{
    public foo;
    constructor(){
        this.foo = 'hey!';
    }
}

class B1 extends A{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}

class B2 {
    public a;
    constructor(){
        this.a = new A();
    }
}

console.log(new B1().foo)
console.log(new B2().a.foo)
```

I get hey in both cases. What is different thou is that I

```
this.foo = 'hey!';
```

You didnt do this. but your code should be giving you a compile time error